# ContentByQueryWebPart: Multiple lists in Powershell

Tags: 2010, list

I have different lists in different Websites that I would like to show in one webpart. I tried it using the ContentByQueryWebPart. By using the GUI, I only can choose one list which isn't enough. In addition to that, I need to solve this problem programmitically with Powershell. What I have so far:

```
$webpartmanager = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($rootSite, [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared);
$webpart = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart;
$webpart.Title = "Information";
$webpartmanager.AddWebPart($webpart, $webpartzone, 2);
```

It works so far, a Webpart with the Title "Information" is succesfully created. I just need the method / property with which I can put in mukltiple lists.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content Query WebPart has a property named `ListsOverride`. This can be used to set multiple lists in CQWP. Set this property with the IDs of the lists. Example:

```
<Lists><List ID="31A7C09D-52CC-4585-B998-A3F180A9BD07"/><List ID="7382D66D-2E4C-47CB-A95C-5EECD68F5E61"/></Lists>
```